# Advertiser identifier using Trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

Here's a question:

How do you get the advertiser identifier using Trigger.io?

I need it to prevent fraud.

I tried the documentation online, but there is no mention.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently exposed in any of the Trigger modules.

However, it would be possible to write your own native module to get access to it, see https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html for details.